# Как исправить ошибку java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android-studio

Делаю своё первое приложение в Android studio и ничего в этом не понимаю. Есть два Activity, и один из них запускается по нажатию кнопки в основном.
Вот код MainActivity:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    int score = 0;
    boolean alive = true;
    String name = "Player";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button playB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button exit = (Button)findViewById((R.id.button3));
        playB.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    Intent i;
    i = new Intent(this, ActivityG.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

А вот код второго Activity:

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityG extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_g);
        int partA = 2;
        int partB = 2;
        int answ = partA*partB;
        int wansw1 = answ - 1;
        int wansw2 = answ + 1;
        TextView textA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);//О, господи, это бъявление объектов в джаве... пипец...
        TextView textB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Button ch1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button ch2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button ch3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        textA.setText(partA);
        textB.setText(partB);
        ch1.setText(answ);
        ch2.setText(wansw1);
        ch3.setText(wansw2);

    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 11018
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.ActivityG}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2583)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:683)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:336)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4465)
        at com.example.test.ActivityG.onCreate(ActivityG.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2530)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:683)
```

Comment: В исключении прямым текстом написано, что не удаётся найти ресурс, к котором у вы обращаетесь. Перепроверяйте идентификаторы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `TextView` есть метод `setText` с двумя перегрузками. Один принимает строку, второй - число.

Вы явно используете второй. Только вот число, которое принимает метод, интерпретируется как ID ресурса. А такого ресурса у вас нет.

Вам надо явно вызывать перегрузку, принимающую строку. Например так:

```
int someInt = 1;
someTextView.setText(String.valueOf(someInt));
```